While creating AWS SQS queue in kotlin getting aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.serde.DeserializationException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0; exception
I am trying to create AWS SQS queue, getting the below error:
aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.serde.DeserializationException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0; found \<, expected one of {, \[, ", null, true, false, \<number\>

validated the SQS client config everything looks good.but when creating the queue facing the above error.
val createQueueRequest = CreateQueueRequest {
queueName =queueNameVal
}

sqsClient.createQueue(createQueueRequest)


Just ran this code example
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val usage = """
        Usage: 
            <queueName> 
        Where:
           queueName - The name of the queue.
        """

    //if (args.size != 1) {
     //   println(usage)
    //    exitProcess(0)
  //  }

    val queueName = "TestQueueJuly" //args[0]
    val queueURL = createQueue(queueName)
    println("The URL: of the new queue is $queueURL")
}

// snippet-start:[sqs.kotlin.create_queue.main]
suspend fun createQueue(queueNameVal: String): String {

    println("Create Queue")
    val createQueueRequest = CreateQueueRequest {
        queueName = queueNameVal
    }

    SqsClient { region = "us-east-1" }.use { sqsClient ->
        sqsClient.createQueue(createQueueRequest)
        println("Get queue url")

        val getQueueUrlRequest = GetQueueUrlRequest {
            queueName = queueNameVal
        }

        val getQueueUrlResponse = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(getQueueUrlRequest)
        return getQueueUrlResponse.queueUrl.toString()
    }
}

It works fine as shown here:

Also - make sure you are using correct SDK for Koltin build values are shown in the Gradle build file here:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/services/sqs
Try using the Kotlin client pattern shown in the code example.
